# I'm getting 500 errors when working with Blocks

Tags: ee2, error-500, blocks

I've got a site that uses Blocks pretty extensively throughout. Up until a few weeks ago, everything was functioning nominally. But recently, trying to save entries that contain more than just a few block types always produces a 500 server error. Needless to say, this makes it nearly impossible to update key sections of the site.

At first, I thought it might be an issue with some of the more complicated blocks that contain lots of fields (e.g., relationship fields), but further tests revealed that it doesn't seem to matter how complicated the blocks are. Adding even 3-4 blocks that just contain basic text fields can result in 500 errors more often than not.

We've reached out to the hosting provider but they haven't been much help. We could always beef up our hosting service (i.e., shell out more money for a more powerful server), but my fear is that would just be a band-aid, and this problem will raise its head again down the line.

Any ideas? Has anyone else run into similar issues with Blocks?

FWIW, the site in question is running on EE 2.11.7 and Blocks 1.4.3 (the most recent versions).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was caused by our site running on an older version of PHP. Upgrading to a more recent version seems to have done the trick.